# Facebook events in news feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy, facebook-events

I can keep pictures that I have been tagged in from showing up in my own timeline and on other people's news feed by simply requiring that those tags get reviewed by me—and not approving them.

How do I keep Facebook from displaying "X is going to an event" in other people's news feed? One solution is to simply not join any event, but I want to be able to tell the event organizers that I am going. I see this as a reasonable thing for Facebook to provide, given other security features (e.g. the picture tagging mentioned above).

Answer (score 1):

If you select the "maybe going" option, it shouldnt show up in your friends newsfeeds.
And if you want the organiser to definitely know you are going, you could send a private message to the organiser, that also wont show up in your friends newsfeeds.

**UPDATE** Facebook have changed things now, and have added a third option of "interested in" event. For public events this has replaced the "maybe" option, but stories about you selecting the "interested in an event" option do now get broadcasted to your friends. For private events, they still have the "maybe" option which works the same way as it used to.